# Automated cygwin install fails with "mount: Access is denied."

Tags: windows, cygwin, unattended-processing

I am trying to create a .bat script that will perform an unattended Cygwin install.

The setup-x86.exe file and package directory are available as a network share mapped to the Z: drive. The script is as follows:

```
Z:\cygwin\setup-x86.exe --local-install --local-package-dir Z:\cygwin\packages --quiet-mode --no-admin
```

When I run the script, I get the Cygwin Setup screen and "Checking prerequisites..." and then a popup entitled "mount" with the message "Access is denied."

I tried adding a '--root C:\Users\username\cygwin' to the command line but got exactly the same result. (Note that the C:\Users\username directory exists and can be written by the current user)

Comment: See http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli You should maybe use the -R option to tell the installer to NOT install cygwin in the default c:\cygwin

Comment: I experience this on Windows 8.1 with the 64 bit Cygwin setup exe even with -R flag provided